# How to bind IDictionary data in a Webgrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, webgrid

i have a ajax call which calls the ControllerName "Floor" and ActionMethod "GetHotelingList".i have a Dropdown list facility. when i select option from the Dropdownlist list the control goes to ajax call.based on selection value, the Webgrid must be displayed. #grdHoteling is Webgrid id.

```
 $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/Floor/GetHotelingList',
                cache: false,
                contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'html',
                data: { floorId: floorId },
                success: function (data) {
                    debugger;
                    $("#grdHoteling").val(data);
                    //debugger;
                    //$("#grdHoteling").html(data);
                },
                complete: function () {
                },
                error: function () {
                    if (facilityName.indexOf('-') != -1) {
                        $('#floor').empty();
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                        alert("Error in generating hoteling information");
                }
            });
```

Here is the ActionMethod GetHotelingList value is paased floorId for some fileration.

```
 public List<IDictionary> GetHotelingList(int floorId)
        {
            var model = new List<IDictionary>();

            using (var context = new FloorContext())
            {
                try
                {
                    model = ListHotelingByFloorId(context, floorId);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
            return model;}
```

On Success of  the ajax call, when i check through debugger am getting data as "System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.IDictionary]" and child cannot be evaluated.

kindly help...!
thanks...!